# Jenkins Job information

Tags: api, jenkins

How to get below mentioned job information by using Jenkins api or some other command line option.

- Time-stamp of last job that succeeded.
- Time-stamp of last job that failed.

I looked in to this API but its giving only build info but not the time stamp i.e at what time and date information when this build failed of succeeded.

http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Job.html

Answer (score 0):

You do this by using the method `getLastSuccessfulBuild()` and `getLastFailedBuild()` on `Job` and then asking each one for their timestamp. E.g. there is no methods for doing this directly on the Job node, instead you need multiple methods.

So, using, for example, the XML API, it would look something like this:

```
https://<JENKINS_URL>/job/<JOB_NAME>/api/xml?tree=lastSuccessfulBuild[timestamp],lastFailedBuild[timestamp]
```

In my case this gives me:

```
<freeStyleProject _class="hudson.model.FreeStyleProject">
  <lastFailedBuild _class="hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild">
    <timestamp>1484291786712</timestamp>
  </lastFailedBuild>
  <lastSuccessfulBuild _class="hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild">
    <timestamp>1486285440897</timestamp>
  </lastSuccessfulBuild>
</freeStyleProject>
```